# Unable to stash file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins pipeline, I am trying to stash a file which exists at given location - `\home\oracle\test\` like  -

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Statsh-Unstash') {
            steps {
                script {
                    node("xyz-server") {
                        stash allowEmpty: true, includes: '/home/oracle/test/testing.txt', name: 'testing', useDefaultExcludes: false
                    }

                    node("xyz-server") {
                        dir('/home/oracle/test-out/') {
                            unstash 'testing'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this, it does not show any file stashed even though file exist at the specified location. On consoled output, I see message -

```
Running on xyz-serveer in /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/DeletePipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stash
Stashed 0 file(s)
```

Please help to understand what is wrong here.

Comment: I believe the `includes` argument is supposed to be an Ant style pattern relative to your workspace directory.

Comment: You're right, it should be relative to workspace directory, but my current path is not in workspace directory hence provided absolute path. But it did not help. I've got solution, will post with answer so it can help to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1: Path of file(s) to stash is inside workspace directory**

Path mentioned in `includes` argument must be relative to workspace directory.

Suppose my workspace directory is `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/` and path for file to stash is `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/testing.txt` then my absolute will be from following path from workspace directory like -

```
 stash allowEmpty: true, includes: 'test/testing.txt', name: 'testing'
```

**Case 2: Path of file(s) to stash is outside of workspace directory**

Suppose my workspace directory is `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/` but path for file to stash is `/home/oracle/test/testing.txt` then I need to enclose stash code with `dir` block which mentions path where file(s) to stash resides and then pass relative path to `includes` argument like -

```
dir('/home/oracle/test/') {
    stash allowEmpty: false, includes: 'testing.txt', name: 'testing'
}
```